# Getting a nested object in C# from Json from a list by specifying a certain attribute

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm getting a Json object back from a HTTP server query.
It is a list of objects wrapped. For example:

```
{
   "RespondingServer":"http://some.url",
   "Value":[
      {
      "Animal":"Donkey",
      "Colour":"Red",
      "Id":"One"
      },
      {
      "Animal":"Elephant",
      "Colour":"Blue",
      "Id":"Two"
      },
      {
      "Animal":"Tiger",
      "Colour":"Yellow",
      "Id":"Three"
      }
    ]
 }
```

What I'd like to do is get an object back with a certain Id field. For example, given the full response object, I'd like a way to get just

```
{
"Animal":"Tiger",
"Colour":"Yellow",
"Id":"Three"
}
```

by specifying an `Id` of `"Three"`

How can I do this in C#? I've tried to do a full JObject parse with

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(responseString);
```

where the `responseString` is the string I get back which denotes the big object. This works, but I'm having the following two issues that are hindering my progress:

1) I can't access named attributes easily. I can't seem to be able to do `jo.Value` to get the list called `Value`. I can only do `jo.Last`, or `jo.GetValue("Value")`

2) If I go with the `jo.GetValue` approach, I can only do this for one level, since I then have a `JToken` and not a `JObject`. For example, I can call `jo.GetValue("Value")`, but I cannot then subsequently call `.GetValue("Animal")` on this.

It is worth noting that the schema for every item in the `Value` list is guaranteed to be the same.

Any pointers on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

---

Editing to add that I have tried creating a C# class that matches the schema to do this. I found I was unable to do so as each item within the `Value` list has one field who's key looks like this `@data.tag`.

An example of each object within the Value list would be:

```
{
"@data.tag":"abcdefg",
"Animal":"Donkey",
"Colour":"Red",
"Id":"One"
},
```

My understanding is that C# can't handle variables starting with `@` (since that's used for reserved names), nor can it handle variables containing a `.`

Comment: You should create a class to which you can deserialize the JSON value. And then access properties of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDhAxk):

```
string responseString = @"{
               ""RespondingServer"":""http://some.url"",
               ""Value"":[
                  {
                  ""Animal"":""Donkey"",
                  ""Colour"":""Red"",
                  ""Id"":""One""
                  },
                  {
                  ""Animal"":""Elephant"",
                  ""Colour"":""Blue"",
                  ""Id"":""Two""
                  },
                  {
                  ""Animal"":""Tiger"",
                  ""Colour"":""Yellow"",
                  ""Id"":""Three""
                  }
                ]
             }";
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(responseString);
JToken token = (jo["Value"] as JArray).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<string>("Id") == "Three");
```

Comment: I've tried it in my code, and this works nicely. Thank you!

Comment: @Azarantara You're welcome. You could find this [tool](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs) useful if you need POCO model for your JSON.